# Message error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Tags: sql-server

That is my SQL Server script:

```
SELECT
    [CaseAttribute],
    LEFT([CaseAttribute], CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) - 1) AS [Function],
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING([CaseAttribute], CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]), LEN([CaseAttribute])), ',', '') AS [Module]
FROM 
    view_CaseAttribute
```

and my string = `'Change shift,Change shift,DInex'`. When I run the script I get an error:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obviously it's not finding any comma, so the result from `CHARINDEX` is 0 and `LEFT` is receiving a -1. Didn't you try modifying your query to find out what's happening? Something like this, for example:

```
SELECT
    [CaseAttribute],
    CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) AS CommaIndex
FROM view_CaseAttribute
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) ASC
```

Another option, to avoid the error:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) > 0 THEN LEFT([CaseAttribute], CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) - 1) END AS [Function],
```

In the end, this was the solution Elina adopted:

```
SELECT [CaseAttribute],
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute], ',', '.'), 3) 'Function',
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute], ',', '.'), 2) 'Module',
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute], ',', '.'), 1) 'Product'
FROM view_CaseAttribute
```

Comment: CharIndex are Null and number.

Comment: If it's NULL, it will return NULL, it won't produce an exception. Is it 0 for any row? For those rows it's not finding the comma.

Comment: I change my script CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) - 1) to CHARINDEX(',', [CaseAttribute]) - 0). And it works now!

Comment: but it removed my others (,)

Comment: But do you want to keep the comma or not? What's your desired output?

Comment: I mean my string='Change shift,Change shift,DInex' and I want the result is: 1. Change shift 2. Change shift 3. DInex. And add them to other different columns. Is that clear?

Comment: But does your string always have 2 commas? Or it may have 1 or 3 or 4? If it's variable, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: SELECT [CaseAttribute],
 PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute],',','.'),3) 'Funtion' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute],',','.'),2) 'Module' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([CaseAttribute],',','.'),1) 'Product'
FROM view_CaseAttribute

Comment: Above sql script also support with NULL :)